# ASP to redirect to jsp with hidden parameters without form

Tags: asp.net, jsp, post, redirect

I have a ASP page where there is a link which is passed to another domain written in JSP.
I need to pass a parameter from ASP page to JSP page but it should be hidden from being caught by user.
On other side in JSP page I will retrieve the parameter and use it accordingly. How can I achieve this?

Comment: What do you men by hidden from being caught by user? not in querystring? is form input hidden field acceptable? encrypted?  Not too clear here.  Another thing... is this just a regular post to jsp or an actual redirect? as in Response.Redirect?

Comment: ya not in querystring and no form it should be done in serverside. Its Response.Redirect.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a [WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx) in the .NET page to the JSP page, set whatever you need on the server side JSP, then redirect to a JSP URL with the server side state already in place.

```
// Create a request for the URL.        
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create ("http://www.contoso.com/default.html");
// If required by the server, set the credentials.
request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
// Get the response.
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse ();
// Display the status.
Console.WriteLine (response.StatusDescription);
// Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream ();
// Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader (dataStream);
// Read the content.
string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd ();
// Display the content.
Console.WriteLine (responseFromServer);
// Cleanup the streams and the response.
reader.Close ();
dataStream.Close ();
response.Close ();

//redirect after
```